# Building Node Js server to receive live Video streams from multiple clients{Raspberry Pi's} over the internet

Tags: node.js

As the title suggests I want to build a NodeJs server to receive live video stream from multiple clients at the same time OVER THE INTERNET.

My client would basically be a Rpi with a camera sending it's live video stream to my NodeJs server.
I would be having multiple clients {Rpis} doing the same.

My NodeJs Server has a Static Public IP.

My NodeJs server and Clients{Rpis} are not on the same Local Network....So how can I send Live Video Stream from Multiple RPis to the central NodeJs server over the internet ?

....Basically I want to Build a VideoStream API[Implemented on NodeJs server], which can be used by my Multiple clients to push frames on to my server. 
I have no clue on how to achieve the above .. Plz Help.

...

I saw many solutions online. None seem to fulfill my purpose.

Most of the solution online said. To configure Rpi as a nodejs server and stream camera feed in  local network but I want to achieve the same on the INTERNET. but this not what I want. Since I have multiple client i.e multiple Raspberry pi's which are not same Network as of the NodeJs server.

Comment: please reformat your question into a question with more clarity so we can assist you

Comment: @Estradiaz i want to send live video stream from multiple Clients{RPis}  to Central NodeJs Server over the internet.

Comment: Note that all those examples that show you local network also work on the internet (they just assume you understand network configurations like port forwarding). I assume your problem is you want to do a push stream instead? This is simple but I'm not sure what you want to do with the streams. Do you just want to save them on disk?

Comment: @slebetman note that all those methods would require me to give all my clients {RPi} a static IP which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

#### client{raspberry pi}

```
const request = require('request');
const readablestream = require('magical-not-provided-way-to-access-camera-stream')
const r = request.post("http://staticIp/");
r.pipe(readablestream);
```

#### server

```
requestlistener(req){req.pipe(writeablestream)}
```

---

#### client

```
raspberrys.foreach(pullStream)
```

#### server{raspberry pi}

```
requestlistener(req,res){res.pipe(camerastream)}
```